# How to setup a developer environment for a python project similar to NodeJs

Tags: python, node.js, git, setuptools, setup.py

**Background Story**
I have a python project which uses setuptools for building the source distribution. Pylint is integrated for running tests. And I come from a heavy NodeJs background.

**Problem**
After doing changes to the code, I have several steps which should be run before distributing the application.

- Run tests
- Run pylint
- Clean build/dist directories
- Build source distribution using setuptools and distutils
- etc etc etc

And some other requirements like,

- Install packages using `pip install -r requirements.txt`
- Activate virtualenv
- Trigger pre-commit & pre-push git hooks (Not yet implemented)

In NodeJs projects, I can write a set of shell commands with **pre** and **post** subscripts in the package.json file which does the job in a real nice way.

Currently for the python project, I am using a shell script which executes the required steps in required order. One other option I thought of was having a package.json just for the sake of handling the dev environment. But it doesn't sound **pythonic!**

How can I automate these steps in an elegant **pythonic** way?

Comment: Unclear what do you mean with _automate_.

Comment: @hoefling For example, if I run some command like `python setup.py pre-build`, then the `pylint`, `tests` and `clean` steps should run in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After doing changes to the code, I have several steps which should be run before distributing the application.

You can chain multiple actions by passing multiple command arguments to the `setup.py` script:

```
$ python setup.py clean test lint sdist build_doc upload
```

You may need additional dependencies if a tool doesn't provide a `distutils` command, for example `pylint` doesn't, so you need `setuptools-lint` package for `python setup.py lint` to work.

You can declare an alias for a command set in a similar way you do this with a Node project. Create a `setup.cfg` file beside your `setup.py` and add the alias:

```
# setup.cfg
[aliases]
ci=clean test lint sdist build_doc upload
```

Now the command above is the same as

```
$ python setup.py ci
```

As for the other requirements, probably [`Pipenv`](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org) is the tool most comparable to `node`. It has neat features like automatic creation and activation of project-specific virtual environment, installation of packages from `Pipfile`, locking of dependencies versions (similar to `shrinkwrap` command), etc.

#### Edit

You can also write custom commands and bind them in your setup script. Example for an `ls` command that runs `ls -l`:

```
from distutils.core import Command
from setuptools import setup


class Ls(Command):

    user_options = []

    def initialize_options(self):
        pass

    def finalize_options(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        self.spawn(['ls', '-l'])


setup(
    name='spam',
    version='0.1',
    author='nobody',
    author_email='nobody@nowhere.com',
    packages=[],
    cmdclass={'ls': Ls,},
)
```

Now run `python setup.py ls` to invoke the new command:

```
$ python setup.py ls
running ls
ls -l
total 8
drwx------  3 hoefling  wheel   96 16 Dez 19:47 
com.apple.launchd.1X84ONyuu4
drwx------  3 hoefling  wheel   96 16 Dez 19:47 
com.apple.launchd.XbjjBY44Mf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root      wheel   64 16 Dez 19:47 powerlog
-rw-r--r--  1 hoefling  wheel  405 16 Dez 19:50 setup.py
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Just one more question, how can I link the `pylint` command or any other custom command to the setup.py?

Comment: First of all, you need the `pytest-runner` dependency if i remember correctly - it provides the `pytest` command for `distutils`. Once installed, you can run `python setup.py pytest` in the same manner as plain `pytest`. You can then also alias `test` to `pytest` in `setup.cfg`  if you use pytest solely for testing.

Comment: my bad. I edited the comment. I typed `pytest` by mistake. Can I run some other custom shell command via setuptools?. For example `rm -r build` to clean a directory?
Anyways, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hmm, afaik it's not possible with vanilla commands, but it's pretty easy to write own command - see [Extending distutils](https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/extending.html) for an example. Let me enhance the answer with a small example.

Comment: Also, i updated the answer with running pylint via `setup.py` - the package `setuptools-lint` adds a `lint` command that invokes pylint.

Comment: Thanks for clearly explaining everything!! Saved my day

Comment: Glad I could help! I added a small example of a custom `distutils` command, but of course there's a lot more that can be done, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using a library for this, [paver](https://github.com/paver/paver) is an option. The documentation [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Paver/getting_started.html#but-people-are-used-to-setup-py) states a way to use paver without changing the way setuptools are used in a project.